# regex to find substring

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a substring BB which may be alone or part of a longer string, e.g. BB or AA|BB|CC or BB|CC or AA|BB i.e. if it follows/is followed by another substring it MUST be  separated by a |. What regex do i need to find  BB in any of the above but not in say AABB?

Comment: Are you trying to find if a string contains |BB| but not AABB, or it is enough the string to contain |BB| ignoring the rest? Or you want to fine positions of all |BB| in a single string?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to find those that are followed by '|' or those that aren't followed by '|'

Comment: make sure to accept an answer if there's a good one. It doesn't need to be mine, but in general you need to accept answers if they've been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
^(.+[|])?BB([|].+)?$
```

And after testing [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) I'm going to say yes, this is it.

Comment: should that last `?` be present since he always wants |CC after the BB

Comment: Actually I thought of that too. However the question ONLY says that `BB` has to have a `|` on either side. It says nothing about OTHER strings. So all I care is that it's `BLAHBLAHBLAH|BB|BLAHBLAHBLAH`.

Comment: @Eric: 6 of one, half dozen of the other

Comment: @Chris: I've just never seen `[]` used to escape characters before.

Comment: @Eric: It's just a character class. Any character inside of [] will be matched once. Yes I could just as easily use `\|`, but I used a character class instead. There's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @Chris: Sure, I see why you used it. It's just an idiom I haven't come across before. Are there any characters that still need to be escaped inside a character class?

Answer (score 4):

If your substrings are limited to alphanumeric characters, you ca use:

```
\bBB\b
```

If they don't, you can simulate the same using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\||^)BB(?=\||$)
```

Your substring should be before and after a pipe, or near the edges.

Comment: "If your substrings are limited to alphanumeric characters..." - *ASCII* alphanumerics, that is.  But I think the lookaround approach is more correct anyway.  Check out my variation, though.  It's not better than yours, just an exercise in mind-expansion. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<![^|])BB(?![^|])");

String[] input = { "AABB", "BB", "AA|BB|CC", "BB|CC", "AA|BBB", "BBB|AA" };
for (String s : input)
{
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  System.out.printf("%-10s : %b%n", s, m.find() );
}
```

output:

```
AABB       : false
BB         : true
AA|BB|CC   : true
BB|CC      : true
AA|BBB     : false
BBB|AA     : false
```

This is effectively the same as @Kobi's answer, but where he's saying the `BB` IS preceded/followed by a pipe or the beginning/end of the string, I'm making the equivalent assertion that it's NOT preceded/followed a character that's NOT a pipe.

Comment: Strange. I always flip lookarounds that check start/end of the string to the opposite lookareand, but couldn't get that one to work. (Oh - I had `[^|]` match new-lines!)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is the position that you want, but this captures where BB starts and ends, if BB is followed by '|' or ends of string:

```
String data = "AA|BB|CCBBCC|BB";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(BB)(?:\\||$)").matcher(data);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " starts at " + m.start() + " ends at " + m.end(1));
}
```

Comment: You need to seal off the front end as well as the back.  As it is, your regex will match the last two `B`'s in `BBB`, `ABB`, `BBB|CC`, etc., and I don't think the OP wants that.

Comment: Not sure what the OP really wants, but he hasn't said anything about if `BB` in `ABB|` should match or not. (Yes, my expression treats it as a match)